# Why I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS while trying to present a view controller?

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

My code is:

```
-(void)playMoviesForItems:(NSArray *)shopItems{
    _moviePlayer = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoPlayerController"];
    [_moviePlayer playMoviesForItems:shopItems];
    [self presentViewController:_moviePlayer animated:NO completion:^{
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectZero animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

In the line that includes presentViewController, I am getting

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=.....)
```

I cannot find why I am getting this. Where am I wrong? How can I debug that?

UPDATE: 
Movie Player is declared like:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) VideoPlayerViewController* moviePlayer;
```

And the code in VideoPlayerController is:

```
-(VideoPlayerViewController*)playMoviesForItems:(NSArray*)items{
playerItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (ShopItem* item in items) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:item.localUrl];
    AVPlayerItem *videoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    [playerItems addObject:videoItem];
}
self.mPlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] init];
self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:mPlayer];
self.playerLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[mPlaybackView setPlayer:self.mPlayer];
currentIndex = 0;
[self initScrubberTimer];    
[self playAtIndex:currentIndex];
mScrubber.maximumValue =  CMTimeGetSeconds(self.mPlayer.currentItem.duration);
mScrubber.value = 0.0;
[self syncScrubber];
[self showOverlays];
return self;
}
```

Sometimes it works clearly. But sometimes it breaks.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint for the exception. In Xcode, switch to the debug navigator. At the bottom, click on the '+' and a popup menu will appear. Select "Add Exception breakpoint..." Now when you run it, the debugger should kick in and you can get a stack trace.

Comment: Can you try commenting out the line [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectZero animated:YES]; and see if it still gives you the same exception? Also make sure that your identifier is correct.

Comment: I commented it out, but still saame error. Identifier is correct, because sometimes I can play the video.

Comment: How is _moviePlayer or the property moviePlayer declared?  What does the body of playMoviesForItems look like?  What line of code do you break on with the exception breakpoint enabled?

Comment: Try to run your code without `[_moviePlayer playMoviesForItems:shopItems];` may be something is wrong with this method

Comment: I commented out [_moviePlayer playMoviesForItems:shopItems] but it still stucks on the same line.